# Can't show line numbers in sublime after editing preferences

Tags: 16.04

I have tried adding line numbers to the side in sublime by adding this line to the distraction free edit file

```
{
"line_numbers": true
}
```

but it still does not show on ubuntu 16.04 how can this be?

Comment: terminal, software?

Comment: It's Sublime Text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add that feature like this:

```
{
    "gutter": true,
    "line_numbers": true
}
```

The `gutter` part and a restart is needed!

Comment: I have added it, it does still not work, should i restart Sublime?

Comment: Yes, please try that!